# RAILS3 // JS executes; COFFEE does not

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Pleased to get started with coffescript in some rails app.
But, after some projects, some difficulties.

The code below translates well, but the coffee one does not do anything

JS :

```
(function(){
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = "/assets/libraries/webfonts.js";
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
WebFontConfig = {
  custom:{
    families: ['tb', 'tr'],
    urls: [ '/assets/1.fonts.css' ]
  }
}
```

COFFEE :

```
(->
  wf = document.createElement("script")
  wf.src = "/assets/libraries/webfonts.js"
  wf.type = "text/javascript"
  wf.async = "true"
  s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
  s.parentNode.insertBefore wf, s
)()
WebFontConfig = custom:
  families: ["tb", "tr"]
  urls: ["/assets/1.fonts.css"]
```

I could list other examples, but I'm fronting this "js works / coffee does not" problem very often

Comment: what is the generated JS code for your CS code. And what error do yu get?

Comment: Not a useful question. What do you mean "works better"? That is a completely nonsense thing to say about code. Either it works, or it doesn't.

Comment: @meagar It does not, as you're accurately saying. Your comment works too; the window context mentioned below was maybe more helpful to understand

Comment: @robkuz I should look at it more often I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Coffee code will translate to a javascript like this:

```
(function(){
  var WebFontConfig;

  (function() {
    var s, wf;
    wf = document.createElement("script");
    wf.src = "/assets/libraries/webfonts.js";
    wf.type = "text/javascript";
    wf.async = "true";
    s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    return s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })();

  WebFontConfig = {
    custom: {
      families: ["tb", "tr"],
      urls: ["/assets/1.fonts.css"]
    }
  };
})
```

As you can see, you are using a WebFontConfig of your context, not window context.

So, I suggest you to do something like this:

```
window.WebFontConfig = custom:
  families: ["tb", "tr"]
  urls: ["/assets/1.fonts.css"]
```

I strongly believe that this will solve your problem.
Also, your Coffee file was execute, it just don't do what you expect.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll dig into this context thing, works perfectly and helped me understand the problem, solving others too. Thx a lot for pointing this out

Comment: you're welcome, I'll take a time to understand this type of issue too.. :)

Comment: I'll think twice when I'll ask something next time. thx again, works perfectly